# How do I resolve this ambiguity?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a field and method with the same name.

```
class Foo {
    String Bar;
    String Bar() { return "woo"; }
}
```

`Error  8   Ambiguity between 'Foo.Bar' and 'Foo.Bar()'`

Can I do this without making `Bar()` an extension method? For example, this works

```
class Foo {
    String Bar;
}

public class Woo {
    public static String Bar(this Foo) { return "woo"; }
}
```

Comment: But *why* do you want a field and a method to have the same name within a class!?

Comment: I am extending functionality in an Entity Model generated from a poorly designed database.

Comment: Are you trying to create a property?

Comment: @nick, can't you modify the way the model is generated?

Comment: What is the *actual* name of the property, per chance?

Comment: @svick Genius. That the solution! Build the model as a smart interface to a dumb database.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram `Make` (as in the make of a car), among many others

Answer (score 10):

You can't. You might be able to find workarounds, like you have, but taken at face value, [the C# spec explicitly forbids this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645760%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The name of a method must differ from the names of all other non-methods declared in the same class. In addition, the signature of a method must differ from the signatures of all other methods declared in the same class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, so just... don't use the same name for a method and field.  It is certainly not necessary in any practical sense and makes for a confusing API anyway.  You're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to deal with entities generated from a database. The question was asked (by me) what the name of the property is.

> Make (as in the make of a car), among many others

Seems like a reasonable name for that property. *Make* is, after all, the accepted name for it. I wouldn't change it. While normally a verb, it is an accepted noun in this usage. To that end, I also wouldn't try to define a method (verb) by that name in that class, for a couple of reasons.

1. Does a car know how to build itself? Does it know how to build another car, or anything else? A car does not build anything. It can get you places, sure. But is the car its own factory? A car is made *by* something. I think you need to create an abstraction for that something.
2. More generally applicable, the entities generated from your database should ideally be left as objects that encapsulate data. Keep the business logic separated from them. You shouldn't need methods in your models with the same name as the properties, even if those properties are poorly named (I don't think *Make* is), because your models simply shouldn't have any* methods. Resolve the ambiguity by not creating it in the first place.

*There are, of course, exceptions, but try to make those truly the exceptions and not the rule.

Comment: The problem is that there was effectively zero design work done on the database. Originally `Make` was a `varchar(50)` but now we are supposed to (but not everyone does) use a separate table of standard makes that we reference with a foreign key. What I did is made a method that checks if the row references the standard make table, and if it doesn't, return the value of the old `Make` `varchar(50)` column. That is why I want a method `Make()` that yields the most correct make value.

Comment: Even in your scenario, `Make()` as a method is a verb. You're not making anything. In this context, it is still a noun, so don't call that method `Make()`. GetMake, RetrieveMake, whatever appropriate verb phrase that fits your overall convention is what I would use in your situation here and elsewhere when your schema is working against you.

Comment: Good point. I seem to have forgotten some basic guidelines of interface design.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691107%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

> a declaration space can never contain a field and a method by the same name

Answer (score 1):

Fields,properties and methods in same class/struct can't have same name
 you need to rename one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot have the field/method with the same name.

However, if you absolutely need this due to a requirement of an interface (which I'm guessing you might want) then you could use [explicit interface implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to resolve any ambiguities.

Comment: Oh, just saw your new comment and the above does not apply to your scenario. Will leave answer here for posterity anyway.